# Operator norm of the matrix polynomial of a self adjoint matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

> Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ self adjoint matrix with eigen values $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \cdots, \lambda_n$.
>
> Let $\|X\|_2 = \sqrt {|x_1|^2 + |x_2|^2 + \cdots + |x_n|^2}$ for $X = (x_1,x_2, \cdots , x_n) \in \Bbb C^n$.
>
> If $p(A) = a_0 I + a_1 A + a_2 A^2 + \cdots + a_n A^n$ then $\mathrm {sup}_{\|X\|_2 = 1}\ \|p(A)X\|_2$ is equal to
>
> $1.\ \ \ \ \mathrm {max} \left \{a_0+ a_1 \lambda_j + a_2 {\lambda_j}^2 + \cdots + a_n {\lambda_j}^n\ :\ 1 \le j \le n \right \}$
>
> $2.\ \ \ \ \mathrm {max} \left \{ \left |a_0+ a_1 \lambda_j + a_2 {\lambda_j}^2 + \cdots + a_n {\lambda_j}^n \right |\ :\ 1 \le j \le n \right \}$
>
> $3.\ \ \ \ \mathrm {min} \left \{a_0+ a_1 \lambda_j + a_2 {\lambda_j}^2 + \cdots + a_n {\lambda_j}^n\ :\ 1 \le j \le n \right \}$
>
> $4.\ \ \ \ \mathrm {min}  \left \{ \left |a_0+ a_1 \lambda_j + a_2 {\lambda_j}^2 + \cdots + a_n {\lambda_j}^n \right |\ :\ 1 \le j \le n \right \}$

I find difficulty to solve it. Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Number (2). The operator norm of a selfadjoint (or normal) matrix $A$ is $\|A\|=\max_j|\lambda_j|$. For any polynomial $p$, the eigenvalues of $p(A)$ are $\{ p(\lambda_j) \}_{j=1}^{n}$. So $\|p(A)\|=\max_{j}|p(\lambda_j)|$, if $A$ is a selfadjoint (or normal) matrix.

To prove this directly for this $A$, let $\{ e_n \}$ be an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $A$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_n$ (allow for repeated eigenvalues.) Then
\begin{align}
    p(A)x & = p(A)\sum_{j=1}^{n}\langle x,e_j\rangle e_j\\
          &  = \sum_{j=1}^{n} p(\lambda_j)\langle x,e_j\rangle e_j. \\
   \|p(A)x\|^2 & = \sum_{j=1}^{n}|p(\lambda_j)|^2 |\langle x,e_j\rangle|^2 \\
     & \le \left(\max_{j}|p(\lambda_j)|\right)^2\sum_{j=1}^{n}|\langle x,e_j\rangle|^2 \\
     & = \left(\max_{j}|p(\lambda_j)|\|x\|\right)^2
\end{align}
From that $\|p(A)\| \le \max_j|p(\lambda_j)|$. The reverse inequality is obtained by choosing $x=e_j$ where $j$ is chosen to maximize $|\lambda_j|$. So $\|p(A)\|=\max_j|p(\lambda_j)|$.

Comment: Do you claim @DisintegratingByParts that $p(A)$ is self adjoint since $A$ is so? But this is not in general true if all $a_i$ are not in the real field.

Comment: @D_C It is normal or selfadjoint

Comment: Can you prove it for normal operators? I already know the result for self adjoint operator but I don't know how to extend the idea of the proof I know for normal operators.

Comment: @D_C A proof of the general result for normal is more difficult than a direct demonstration for this case. So I added the direct demonstration.

Comment: Oh! Really good and understandable proof even for the beginners . Thank you very much @DisintegratingByParts for your help.

Comment: Can you tell me where will I find the proof for normal operators?

Comment: @D_C : The general case of a normal operator on a Hilbert space is handled by showing that the norm $\|N\|$ of a normal operator is the same as its spectral radius, $r_{\sigma} = \sup_{\lambda\in\sigma(N)}|\lambda|$. This is done by showing that $(N-\lambda I)$ has a bounded inverse for $|\lambda| > \lim_n \|N^n\|^{1/n}$ by using a Laurent series construction of the inverse: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\lambda^{n+1}}N^{n}$. (You can verify that $(\lambda I-N)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\lambda^{n+1}}N^n=I$.)

Comment: @D_C : For the normal matrix $N$, you can easily extend what I gave in the solution by using the fact that $N$ has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors.

Comment: What's an example of non-self-adjoint operator for which this is not true?